# How to use text watcher in Expandable ListView to filter text

Tags: android

I used this code but it gives me Error

```
searchbox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence key, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                ((Filterable) xad).getFilter().filter(key);
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

xad = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list, childmap);
        listview.setAdapter(xad);
```

where xad is my `ExpandableListAdapter`. Do I have to do some changes in the `getView()` method of the Adapter class?

My LogCat:

```
 04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.testappNew.ExpandableListAdapter
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at com.example.testappNew.CallLogActivity$1.onTextChanged(CallLogActivity.java:102)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6598)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6645)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6789)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:654)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:180)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:120)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:283)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:79)      
04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    04-21 17:59:06.615: E/AndroidRuntime(14845):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? How should anyone help you if you don't explain what the problem is?

Comment: Your Adapter class actually has to implement `Filterable`. You can't just cast it as such.

Answer (score 0):

use this in Main class

```
editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String text = editsearch.getText().toString()
                        .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
            }
        });
```

USe this code part in Adapter class. In this code I am using offer_name for filtering and perform search operation.

```
// Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        item.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            item.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (OfferItem wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getoffer_name().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    item.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I just want to filter the Group list not Child List.

Comment: define this  private List<Item class name> item = null;

Comment: @donison did you get solution..?

Comment: Sorry Amardeep, but what is Class name here?   private List<Item class name> item = null;

Comment: where you used getter and setter method to hold and retrive value in listview